React RenderProps TypeScript
I'm trying to define a render props function type that will capture the props type (P) of the element that is returned (T).
What I have so far (but it doesn't work):
type ParentType = {
  render?: <P, T extends ReactElement<P>>(props: P) => T
}

I want to use it like this (Parent is of type ParentType above):
<Parent render={(p) => <Child {...p} />} />

It seems simple but I get the following error:
Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'T'.
     'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'Element'.

Your help is very much appreciated!

What are you trying to achieve with:  T extends ReactElement?
It looks redundant in the example, as you could just use type ParentType = {
render?: (props: P) => React.ReactElement;
};

T is the type of the returned element with props of type P.

Do you expect it to be something different than ReactElement? Do not quite get why ReactElement won't suffice. Would be nice if you could provide one particular example in your question, so that it becomes possible to debug it

The returned element has some required props that are provided by the Parent component but without them I get a TypeScript error that required props are missing from the Child
